# In android studio, sqlite database is not created but no error in my code

Tags: android, sqlite

At first I got a message "cant build to local 8600 for debugger" then someone says to update the jre version from 7 to 8, then I got a message like "device does not match the local build on disk" then afterwards My code runs without any message, but database is not created. here is my mainclass,

```
 package com.kaizen.sqlitedatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Sqlite mydb;
    TextView name,surName,marks;
    EditText edtName,edtSurName,edtMarks;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mydb=new Sqlite(this);

        name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        surName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.surName);
        marks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.marks);
        edtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        edtSurName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_surName);
        edtMarks=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_marks);
}
}
```

Here is my subclass of sqlite openhelper,please somebody help me

```
package com.kaizen.sqlitedatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Naveen on 05-10-2016.
 */

public class Sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASENAME="STUDENTS_DATABASE.db";
    public static final String TABLENAME="STUDENTS_MARKS";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="STUDENT_NAME";
    public static final String COL_3="SUR_NAME";
    public static final String COL_4="MARKS";

    public Sqlite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLENAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER) ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLENAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kaizen.sqlitedatabase.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/edt_name" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/surName"
            android:text="Sur Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/edt_surName" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/marks"
            android:text="Marks" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/edt_marks" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not created?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to create table, i think problem is in your query

```
String CREATE_TABLE_CITY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + NAME+ " TEXT, " + SURNAMENAME+ " TEXT, " + MARKS+ " INTEGER )";

 mDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CITY);
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to check your database is create or not then go...

Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor

Click on your device on the left.

Go to File Explorer (one of the tabs on the right), go to /data/data/databases

Select the database by just clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

in new version of android studio you can check database create or not.

Click on:
 View > Tool Windows > File Explorer > data > data > find your application name > database

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `SQLiteOpenHelper` is that it doesn't call the `onCreate` method by only creating its object.

- Whenever you try to access the database for retrieving or inserting data, if the database is not already created, it will call the `onCreate` method for the first time.
- The `onUpgrade` method will be called if the database is available but the version is lower than the one you provide.

So that please try to run some queries and then check the database is created.

Database created location is 
**View -> Tool Windows -> Device file Explorer -> data -> data ->  -> database**